# Chrome NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM Error on Windows

Tags: google-chrome

Every time when I search for a URL that starts with `https`, Google Chrome shows the error:

> **Your connection is not private**
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from **chrome.google.com** (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).  NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM

I don't what is wrong is their any problem in Internet settings or with Google Chrome. How can I fix this?

[image: "Your connection is not private" error]

Answer (score 0):

This problem's fix in Linux is running in terminal: sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
& since you're working on windows, to get the missed library it's pretty hard to find and install it as a one, so it's much easier to uninstall & re-install Google chrome will completely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Open chrome then press f12 ( win+f12 or ctrl +f12 )
2 - Open Security tap and view certificate ( red ! ) should be seen
3 - check Issued by ( my case was Superfish Inc ) this is the software that makes your error. SSL certificate not trusted.

https://support.lenovo.com/my/en/product_security/superfish_uninstall

please check this link for superfish Inc removal if your case is same if not check manual removal part.
Manual remove :
1- control panel-> add remove program -> remove program which was seen in step 3.

2- In windows start menu search for Certificate. choose manage computer certificates.

3- Open trusted Root certification and choose expired certificate that was found in step 3 .  Right click in that and delete it.

4- MOST important part of computer world RESTART NOW :D

I hope it be useful for you .

Answer (score 0):

This specific error is caused by an SSL certificate used to secure the site not having a strong enough encryption algorithm. The owner of the website will need to re-issue their SSL cert using a stronger algorithm.